# image magick problem with java

Tags: java, image, bash, imagemagick, resize

to  be specific in this i'm trying to run the next line on java:

```
 convert /home/mohamed.hegab/Desktop/1263392123111.jpg -gamma .45455 -resize 400x400 -gamma 2.2 -quality 92 /home/mohamed.hegab/Desktop/small.jpg
```

which is run great on the bash command line 
but when i run it on the java using process builder it gives me strange result.

```
public static void resizeImage(String srcPath, String destPath,String size) {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("convert", srcPath , " -gamma", ".45455",
                " -resize",size, " -gamma ", "2.2", " -quality",
                "92" , destPath);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();
            isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception while trying to convert text to image", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if(isr != null) {
                    isr.close();
                }
                if(br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error("Could not close stream", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

the line that comes in the system.out is strange and weird it says that

---

convert: unable to open image `-gamma': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2439.
convert: unable to open image`.45455': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2439.
convert: unable to open image `-resize': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2439.
convert: unable to open image`400x400': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2439.
convert: unable to open image `-gamma ': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2439.
convert: unable to open image`2.2': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2439.
convert: unable to open image `-quality': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2439.
convert: unable to open image`92': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2439.

---

but the images is comes out only with the size 960 *960  which i don't know where it comes from .

so can any one help me in this :)

Comment: Hi Mohamed Emad Hegab,how did you prepare static build for image magick? can you please share code

Answer (score 3):

Avoid the blanks before the `-`, shell commands can only recognize options that start with `-`.

Comment: unfortanatly that's not the answer :) i found it any way and it works fine.. i'll put it in the answer of the Question. thanks for the effort man :)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is here in this link

http://www.darcynorman.net/2005/03/15/jai-vs-imagemagick-image-resizing/

simply i should cut the command to pieces in array and run it normally without process builder